# Are these the correct permissions (644 and 755) for files and directories on a web server?

Tags: permissions

Am I correct that the most secure (yet practical) permissions for files and directories on a public web server are:

- Files - 644

  - user - rw (can view and edit but the files are not executables)
  - group/world - read only (don't need to edit or execute)
- Directories - 755

  - user - rwx (entering a directory is an 'execute' statement)
  - group/world - rx (view the directory listing and enter the directory but not write files to it)

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: I believe this depends heavily on the nature of the web server. I would also guess that the best settings for the specific use you have for your server is likely already well documented wherever your server's setup is documented. So, we need more information before we can answer you, and it would help to know what research you've done before asking here.

Answer (score -1):

`644` (`u=rw,go=r`) and `755` (`u=rwx,go=rx`) definitely are **not** the most secure permissions for a web server!

Consider the "need to know" principle.
For example:

- Does every user need to read all files?
- Does every user need to list
  all directories?

If your web server runs with uid `webserver`, why not give read permissions for all files and execute permission to all directories for `webserver` only?
Then you would have to decide who (if ever) is going to be allowed to update/create/remove any files.

Also if the system supports ACLs (`setfacl`, `getfacl`), consider using them.
I.e.: Assign rights to indicidual users instead of groups or world.

Comment: While well intentioned, this is ultimate an opinion-based question that is resulting in a vague answer. In all honesty, the state 644/755 permissions are 100% fine and standard in many installs. For most people this is as “secure” as needed. If there are other needs, of course increased permission restrictions are warranted. But there is no “one answer” for this.

Comment: Assuming 0644/0755 is the default, I wonder what the OP is really asking for.

Comment: “I wonder what the OP is really asking for.” Exactly.